# New vanity and moving the plumbing

Tags: plumbing

How do I move the plumbing to the left about a foot? The picture shows the main pipe originally was moved to the right about a foot but now I need to move it to the left. I would like it lined up with where the pipe originally was.
[image]
Also, the vanity only has one hole for the sink and my other one has 3 holes for the sink, so how do I prepare the lines for one whole ?

Comment: Your questions are a bit vague. You move the pipes by moving the pipes. What part of the process has you stumped? As to the vanity, you make new holes as needed. What about that is troublesome? Please edit your post to ask more clear, specific questions. It sounds like you just need to do some reading about basic plumbing, though.

Answer (score 1):

The supply line and your drain lines are likely teed behind the wall, above the cut-out section. My guess is the vent pipe runs vertical out of the tee with the drain, so it won't need to move. You might be able to simply cut the pipes coming out of the tees, add couplers, and run new connections straight out. Or you might need to replace the tees with ones rotated properly. Before starting, make sure you know exactly what your plan is, ensure the water is shut off from the source, and if you're not confident in your ability to make straight cuts and new plumbing connections, call a plumber or a general handyman.

For your second question, it just means your vanity is expecting a single-hole faucet. These still accept both supply lines, of course; they just screw into the mixer valve under the countertop. If your vanity didn't come with a faucet, you'll need to buy a new one as your old three-hole faucet won't work (unless you can drill new holes in the vanity).